# H2 database> How to compact / vacuum while running?

Tags: java, h2

### Heading

In one of my projects I am using h2 database with file storage.

According to h2 db [documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compacting)

> "Empty space in the database file [is] re-used automatically. When closing the database, the database is automatically compacted for up to 200 milliseconds by default."

Empty space is created every time a row is deleted or updated. Unfortunately at runtime the database file is growing continuously.

In [this](http://groups.google.com/group/h2-database/browse_thread/thread/0865ce7d2c7f56ae) discussion it is suggested to backup the database, and restore it again.
However I am searching for a solution to compact / vacuum the database at runtime, without shutting down. Is there a way do achieve this?

Of course it is an option to migrate to a database like Postgres. However my project should be very easy to install, so it would be necessary to integrate it into the installer. In general adding a dedicated database adds some overhead.

Comment: Do you know why the database file is growing continuously? Unless you always add more data than you delete, this shouldn't be the case.

Comment: Hi Thomas. Thanks for your question! The problem is in fact adding and updating. H2db appends to the end of the file, but the "deleted" space within the file is not reused.

Comment: That's strage. Do you have a short, self contained, compilable, example (http://sscce.org/) of the problem?

Comment: Hi Thomas. I'll provide exactly that in about 10 days. I am leaving Europe for some days this evening, so unfortunately I cannot provide it earlier. Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasMueller: I followed your advice (thanks again!) and created a short test program, available here: https://rapidshare.com/files/2763279683/h2db.vacuum.test.zip New knowledge: 
 - H2DB's file does indeed grow, even when only one or two lines are updated all the time, and no new data is added
 - **There is an upper limit to growth (file size never exceeds 40,9 MB)**
 - This limit is independent of the number of rows that are in the database, or the number of tables. As my only worry was an infinite growth of the file , I am quite happy know and regard my own question as answered

Comment: I didn't analyze the test program yet, but the upper limit is most likely the transaction log size. You can set it to a lower value using SET MAX_LOG_SIZE 4 or by appending ;MAX_LOG_SIZE=4 to the database URL (see also the docs).